# Is there an alternate method of displaying specific data from a database using php?

Tags: php, html

Let me take a minute to explain what I am desiging. Note this is not a project I plan on taking live. I am currently creating a php Point of sale system using php and mysql. The system works like this, I am to insert the customers date of birth an generate a price based on their age. I obtain basic credentials like first and last name along with DOB and the price that is automatically generated.

On the payment page I want to display the price above the forms that retrieve the users credit/cash payments, however if there is more than one order in the database the code will simply select all of the information and display it. See the link below for an image.

Payment Page of application:

[image: Payment Page of application]

Below is the information displayed in the database:
[Image of information in the database:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zPR1b.jpg)

If a new order is created I would like for the price that corresponds to a specific order # to be displayed. Below is the code I have generated for a solution:

```
<?php 

$sql = "SELECT Total FROM orders";
$result = mysqli_query($connection,$sql);
// Selects total from the database and displays it.
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
$total = $row['Total'];
echo "The total is $" . "{$total}";
// $change = $total - $cash_recieved ;
// echo $change;
}

?>
```

Its a simple while loop that display data from the database. I know its far from right but it's the only solution that I have come up with. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php 
$sql = "SELECT Total FROM orders where Order = ".$theorderidyouwant;
$result = mysqli_query($connection,$sql);
$theorder = $result[0];
$total = $theorder["Total"];

echo "The total (for order #".$theorderidyouwant.")is $".$total;  //tada
?>
```

Comment: What exactly do you need clarification on ?

Comment: Apart from the code amendment (assuming it is what you were looking for), the rest of your question very much depends on how you are doing everything else. Do these orders belong to a cart ? To a user ? Do the carts belong to the user ? Are you using the DB to keep track of [various things] ? Session ? Cookies ? And so on.

Comment: There is no cart. The orders are being generated by say a cashier. Take a look at the data base image I recently provided. Every time a new order is created I would like to display the price for that unique order. Hope that helps.

Comment: So the order IS the cart ? Meant of course as the container of the individual products.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by "cart", but allow me to further explain. If you click here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/zPR1b.jpg you will see two order. I What is happening now is the the price for both orders are being displayed. Because I am now creating a NEW order I only want the price for order # 38 to be displayed and so on and so forth. How can I achieve this task? Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Edited the answer.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand this correctly, you want to make a new order, generate a price for it then go to the payment page and show the total for the order you just created.

Assuming that you know the primary key of the order that you generated:

```
// assuming that $orderKey contains the primary key of the order
$sql = "SELECT Total FROM orders WHERE `Order` = {$orderKey}";
$result = mysqli_query($connectionHandle, $sql);
if ( count($result) > 0 ) {
    $order = $result[0];
    echo "{$order['Total']}";
}
else {
    echo "No order found";
}
```

Is this on track with what you are asking?